# Require statement not working in ruby from bash

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, require

I'm trying to get ttscoff's TaskPaper to Markdown ruby script https://gist.github.com/511174 working. However, I use rvm, which seems to present some challenges.

`-rjcode` is a no-longer needed Unicode flag and -Ku is another encoding flag I can probably ignore.

I found instructions for adding rvm as a function to your script, but the script still errors as soon as it hits `require ftools`.

What I added is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# TaskPaper to Markdown converter
# Usage: tp2md.rb filename.taskpaper > output.md
# Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*


# Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
if [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] ; then
  # First try to load from a user install
  source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
elif [[ -s "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] ; then
  # Then try to load from a root install
  source "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"
else
  printf "ERROR: An RVM installation was not found.\n"
fi

# Configure ruby and gemset
rvm ruby-1.9.2-p290@global

ruby <<-rb
  puts "Hello!"
rb
```

`Hello!` outputs fine, but I get the following errors afterwards:

```
require: command not found
infile: command not found
prevlevel: command not found
begin: command not found
syntax error near unexpected token `('
`    file = File.new(infile, "r")'
```

My problem seems to be related to the gem not getting pulled in. I've uninstalled ftools and reinstalled with rvm, but still no dice. Thankful for any help!

Comment: The real problem is that, somewhere, a ruby script is being interpreted by bash (those are all bash error messages).

Answer (score 0):

Your telling ruby to load the 'b' library.

`-r library     Causes Ruby to load the library using require.  It is useful when using -n or -p.`

This should work.

```
ruby -r ftools <<rb
  puts "Hello!"
rb
```

Comment: No, that's not it, "-rb" is a valid here-document word, the hyphen means that leading tabs are removed from the document.